# How to set the DataFlavor of a Component?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, transfer

I'm not really sure if i have understood the principe of the DataFlavors correctly, but how can i actually set the DataFlavor(s) of a JComponent?
Every time i call the getDataFlavor method the output is this:

```
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-file-list;representationclass=java.util.List]
```

My problem is, that i want to drag images from the desktop or any other place right into my JPanel. It's working through the DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, but is there no way that i can create a custom flavor which only accepts PNG and JPG Files for example?
(I know that it is actually possible to create Custom Flavors but i have no clue how i can "enable" the new created flavors for my components)

Or is there a way to ensure whether the dragged in Item is a PNG or JPG with the javaFileListFlavor?

I hope that i could explain my question well enough (I'm not a master of this language, but i'm trying my best ;) )

Comment: How are you handling the component's TransferHandler?

Comment: I am not at the PC atm but i just have a class which extends TransferHandler and overrides the canİmport(...) and the importData(...) method. The canİmport is a one liner and just returns true (Because i dont know how to get the transferred Data), the importData function however gets the Transferable and through the dataFlavor i have been able to create a List of Files which then contains the File of my Image at index 0, if the drop is succesful. Afterwards im adding the transferHandler through the setTransferHandler() Method of my panel

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a way to ensure whether the dragged in Item is a PNG or JPG with the javaFileListFlavor?

Take a look at the Swing tutorial on [Top Level Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html). It shows how to drag a file from the desktop to a JTextArea.

Take a look at the `canImport(...)` and `importData(...)` methods of the `TransferHandler`. The `canImport(...)` method currently only checks that you have a FileListFlavor. So you would need to add extra logic to see the actual File is a PNG or JPG.

If you look at the `importData(...)` method you can see how to get the File object from the TransferSupport object so you can implement the above check.

Edit:

> but as described the Exception pops up

I just ignore the Exception. Here is the modified code for the tutorial that only allows your to copy ".java" files into the text area.

```
private TransferHandler handler = new TransferHandler() {
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }

        Transferable t = support.getTransferable();

        try
        {
            java.util.List<File> l = (java.util.List<File>)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            File file = l.get(0);
            String fileName = file.getName();

            if (!file.getName().endsWith(".java"))
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ignore
        }

        if (copyItem.isSelected()) {
            boolean copySupported = (COPY & support.getSourceDropActions()) == COPY;

            if (!copySupported) {
                return false;
            }

            support.setDropAction(COPY);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Works fine for me using JDK8 on Winodow 7.

Comment: It's not possible to get the File object from the TransferSupport object because you would have to get the Transferable of the TransferSupport and by doing this you would provoke an InvalidDnDOperationException, or am i wrong?

Comment: "The canImport(...) method currently only checks that you have a FileListFlavor". Do you have any ideas to change that? I googled for a while but i didn't find a proper solution.

Comment: @SaliKe, `or am i wrong?` - I don't know, I'll let you try it and see what happens.